# input field and css transform scale is not working properly in chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, transform, scaletransform

CSS transform scale on input element moves value text beyond the container when height property is not auto.

But with scale3d it seems like ok. I was able to repeat it in Chromium (30.0.1599.114) and Chrome (31.0.1650.63), maybe it is webkit bug.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.2.js"></script>
  <style>
   .phone-first { height: 30px; }
  </style>
</head>
  <body>
    <input class="phone-first" type="text" name="phone" value="+71231231213">
    <br><br><br>
    <input class="phone-second" type="text" name="phone" value="+71231231213">
    <br><br><br>
    <a href="#" class="p">scale 2</a>
    <br>
    <a href="#" class="m">scale 1</a>
    <br><br><br>
    <a href="#" class="p3d">scale3d 2</a>
    <br>
    <a href="#" class="m3d">scale3d 1</a>

    <script>
        var $phone = $('.phone-first, .phone-second');
        $('.p').click(function() { $phone.css('transform', 'scale(2, 2)'); });
        $('.m').click(function() { $phone.css('transform', 'scale(1, 1)'); });
        $('.p3d').click(function() { $phone.css('transform', 'scale3d(2, 2, 2)'); });
        $('.m3d').click(function() { $phone.css('transform', 'scale3d(1, 1, 1)'); });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/j67H3/ - here is an example.

Any workaround or more info about this? Am I missing something?

Thanks.

Comment: No idea. Good question though. I tried to get it running on Mozilla, but I seem to encounter compatibility errors there.

Comment: @MrLister, what kind of error do you have? Need more info. I tested in Firefox current, it's ok.

Comment: Sorry, I seemed to have adblocked scripts on jsFiddle.net by mistake. It's fine now.

Answer (score 0):

I changed your example just removing the css(height) and everything went as expected - no error

Comment: Yes, it's true. But what if I need a non-standard height?.. So, https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=327023&thanks=327023&ts=1386610783

I think this is chromium/chrome bug.

Comment: ai do not know what to tell you because I did not find any other solution